# Android current users account information

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am getting the name and phone number of all the contact information on the user's phone but the name and picture of the phone's current user doesn't appear in this list.

```
Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
    String trimedNumber = phoneNumber.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]", "").replaceAll(" ","");
    if(trimedNumber.length()<10) 
    {
        return returnValue;
    }
    trimedNumber = trimedNumber.substring(trimedNumber.length()-10, trimedNumber.length()-1);

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);

    if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        return returnValue;
```

How can I get the current user's information?

Answer (score 0):

By current user, I assume you mean the owner of the phone. This problem cannot always be solved, but here is a method to get the owners number:

```
/*
 * Tries to get the user's phone number. Note that there is no guaranteed solution to this problem because the phone
 * number is not physically stored on all SIM-cards, or broadcasted from the network to the phone. This is especially 
 * true in some countries which requires physical address verification, with number assignment only happening 
 * afterwards. Phone number assignment happens on the network - and can be changed without changing the SIM card 
 * or device (e.g. this is how porting is supported).
 */
private String getPhoneNumber() {
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String phoneNumber = telephonyManager.getLine1Number();
    if (phoneNumber != null) return PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(phoneNumber);
    else return phoneNumber;
}
```

Comment: Yes I have the owners number but I am looking for the owners name like Bob smith and the photo he has on his google account